# C++ strcpy_s IntelliSense error

Tags: c++, intellisense, tr24731

I have error in this place:

```
strcpy_s(msgToGraphics, game.board_now());
```

the error is:

```
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "strcpy_s" matches the argument list argument types are: (char [1024], std::string)
```

and here is the game.board_now func:

```
string Board::board_now()
{
return _board;
}
```

and here is the rest of the code where I try to use the `strncpy_s()`:

```
#include "Pipe.h"
#include "Board.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    srand(time_t(NULL));

    Pipe p;
    bool isConnect = p.connect();

    string ans;
    while (!isConnect) {
        cout << "cant connect to graphics" << endl;
        cout << "Do you try to connect again or exit? (0-try again, 1-exit)" << endl;
        cin >> ans;

        if (ans == "0") {
            cout << "trying connect again.." << endl;
            Sleep(5000);
            isConnect = p.connect();
        }
        else {
            p.close();
            return;
        }
    }

    char msgToGraphics[1024];
    // msgToGraphics should contain the board string accord the protocol
    // YOUR CODE
    Board game;
    //strcpy_s(msgToGraphics, game.board_now()); // just example...

    p.sendMessageToGraphics("rnbkqbnrpppppppp################################PPPPPPPPRBNKQNBR0"); // send the board string

    // get message from graphics
    string msgFromGraphics = p.getMessageFromGraphics();

    while (msgFromGraphics != "quit") {
        game.change_board(msgFromGraphics);
        game.change_board_sq(msgFromGraphics);
        strcpy_s(msgToGraphics, game.board_now()); // msgToGraphics should contain the result of the operation

        // return result to graphics
        p.sendMessageToGraphics(msgToGraphics);

        // get message from graphics
        msgFromGraphics = p.getMessageFromGraphics();
    }

    p.close();
}
```

The code is basically for a chess program and I try to recieve the chess board after the changes I made and I dont know how to format him in the `strcpy_s()` in order to put him in the array and send it back to the given exe.

Comment: Why isn't `msgToGraphics` an `std::string` as well? You can avoid a lot of headaches avoiding plain `char` arrays, and in this case you could just assign one string to the other through the operator =, as in `msgToGraphics = game.board_now();`.

Comment: because it has to be array because this is what the interface recives

Comment: That's not a good reason. You can use string::c_str() to pass a character pointer to your API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since C11 strcpy_s is**

```
1) `char *strcpy( char *dest, const char *src );`  
2) errno_t strcpy_s(char *restrict dest, rsize_t destsz, const char *restrict src);
```

**strcpy_s** is  Same as (1), 
except that it may clobber the rest of the destination array with unspecified values and that the following errors are detected at runtime and call the currently installed constraint handler function:

- **src** or dest is a `null` pointer
- **destsz** is zero or greater than RSIZE_MAX
- **destsz** is less or equal `strnlen_s(src, destsz);` in other words, truncation would occur
- **overlap** would occur between the source and the destination strings

  1. The behavior is undefined if the size of the character array pointed to by dest <= `strnlen_s(src, destsz) < destsz;` in other words, an erroneous value of destsz does not expose the impending buffer overflow.
  2. As all bounds-checked functions, `strcpy_s` is only guaranteed to be available if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`  is defined by the implementation and if the user defines `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__`  to the integer constant 1 before including `string.h`.

Refer the page for more information http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to make `msgToGraphics` a `std::string` too, and then instead of using the C function `strcpy_s`, just assign to it to do the same thing:

```
msgToGraphics = game.board_now();
```

If you need to get a non-const `char*` to the underlying array, you can do it like this (with the usual caveats):

```
p.sendMessageToGraphics(&msgToGraphics[0]);
```

But really you should change the interface to not rely on a char array being passed in. (Hint: use `std::string` instead.)